# Jinja templating in javscript

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask, and I am trying to send data to my html page. The obvious choice is Jinja templating: `{{ input_msg }}`, but the problem is I need I am inside curly brackets already, since I need to put the variable into javscript:

```
request.onload = function() {
if (request.status === 200 && request.responseText === 'done') {
    window.location = {{ inp_msg }};
}
};
```

The above will not work because curley brackets are being used for templating, but inside javscript as well. Is there another way to send data, not jinja? If not, is there another jinja way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.location` would expect a string

Comment: This would work if you put quotes around it: `window.location = "{{ inp_msg }}";` and the file is being rendered as a jinja template. JS won't see the braces - `{{ inp_msg }}` will be expanded to some string value when rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a string for window.location.

```
window.location = '{{ inp_msg }}'
```

Also use can use `url_for` function.

```
window.location = '{{ url_for(func_name) }}'
```